# Can i move samba from device to another?

Tags: software-installation, samba, oracle-linux

I downloaded the samba on my operating system (Oracle Linux 8), I want to copy it to another device that have the same operating system but without internet connection.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say you "dowloaded the samba" - what exactly did you download? An RPM package? A .tar.gz-achive?

Comment: I downloaded samba using this command: sudo yum install samba

Comment: Now i need to move it to another device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If prior to installing samba these two systems had **the same set** of packages, you do the following.

1. Run `rpm -qa --last | head -30` and identify the packages that you installed
2. Run the following command `dnf reinstall --downloadonly package1 package2 package3 ...`
3. Find all these RPMs in `/var/cache/dnf`
4. Copy them to a new PC into a single directory
5. On the new PC run `sudo rpm -ivh *rpm` in this directory.

If the states of systems were different, these instructions may not work.

Comment: Thank you, it's working